# Android : Payment Processing

Tags: android, payment-processing

I've referred lot of things for payment processing system to android app. It proviedes [Paypal's SDK](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk) as best to do. But, i've little confusion in there for below image -

What's the difference between these two - **Mobile Express Checkout Library** & **Mobile Payment Libraries**. And, which one will i choose to do the payment processing for android app. Anyone please, explain with brief explanation please. Thanks in Advance.

[image: Payment Processing]

Comment: Shall i know why downvote? I'm just beginner. Don't i have right to ask here?

Comment: Someone who didn't leave a comment.  +1 to balance.

Comment: Thank you. I like `Stackoverflow Rules`

Comment: @GalaxyS2 hey are you from INDIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope this will help you :

> Mobile Payment Libraries (MPL): Add in-app payments by just adding a
>   Pay with PayPal button to your iOS or Android app. PayPal’s library
>   will display an in-app UI to ask the buyer to log in and complete the
>   payment. It's the quickest way to add payments into your app, and you
>   can do it without having back-end services running.
>
> Mobile Express Checkout Library (MECL): If you want the PayPal
>   checkout flow to be in a browser or webview, you can use our Mobile
>   Express Checkout Library. This is useful if you already have a express
>   checkout integration completed for your website or if app store
>   policies require you to complete your checkout flow in a browser. This
>   library will help you integrate the mobile web flow into your app.

I got this information from [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-overview).

Comment: Yes it's very useful for me. Thanks you. I've been waiting for this explanation.